# onload function on iframe is getting called twice in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have an iframe in html which have a onload function in it. In IE11 the onload function is getting called twice while in chrome it works fine.

HTML:

```
   <iframe src="someurl" onload="someFunction()"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
 function someFunction() {

   $window.scroll(0, 0);

   if (count > 0) {
       $ctrl.iframeHeight = '1000px';
       $scope.$digest();
   }

   return count++;

 }
```

someFunction() is getting called twice in IE11.

Comment: What's inside someFunction() ? may be it create some conflict.

Comment: Show your code what you have written inside `someFunction()`. So we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I think should check JavaScript file / Library reference on your page. It might be because of one js file reference is added twice.

I came across similar problem for ajax call when jquery ajax js file reference is added twice.

Please check if you have similar problem.